# Skewness and kurtosis of sum of independent variables

Tags: statistics

Suppose $M=aX+bY+cZ$.

I would like to calculate $\operatorname{skew}(M)$ and $\operatorname{Kurt}(M)$. Then how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, then you can find the first, second, third and fourth raw moments of $M$ in terms of the  third and fourth raw moments of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.  Similarly the second, third and fourth moments about the means.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example, like the way, var(ax+by)=a^2var(x)+b^2var(y).

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming $X,Y,Z$ are mutually independent:*

Using $m_1$ for the first raw moment about zero so $m_1(M)=\mathbb E[M]$, $m_2$ for the second raw moment about zero $m_2(M)=\mathbb E[M^2]$, $m_3$ for the third, $m_4$ for the fourth, you have $$m_j(M) = a^jm_j(X)+b^jm_j(Y)+c^jm_j(Z)$$

That would also work if $X,Y,Z$ had zero means, so in general using $\mu_2$ for the second moment about the mean (i.e. variance or $\sigma^2$),  $\mu_3$ for the third moment about the mean, $\mu_4$ the fourth, you have 
$$\mu_j(M) = a^j\mu_j(X)+b^j\mu_j(Y)+c^j\mu_j(Z)$$

So $\mu_2(M) = a^2\mu_2(X)+b^2\mu_2(Y)+c^2\mu_2(Z)$, i.e. $$\sigma^2(M) = a^2\sigma^2(X)+b^2\sigma^2(Y)+c^2\sigma^2(Z)$$

while the skewness of $M$ is the third moment about the mean standardised (let's call it $\hat\mu_3(M)$) $$\hat \mu_3(M) = \frac{\mu_3(M)}{\sigma^3(M)} = \frac{a^3\mu_3(X)+b^3\mu_3(Y)+c^3\mu_3(Z)}{(a^2\mu_2(X)+b^2\mu_2(Y)+c^2\mu_2(Z))^{3/2}} \\ = \frac{a^3\hat\mu_3(X)\sigma^3(X)+b^3\hat\mu_3(Y)\sigma^3(Y)+c^3\hat\mu_3(Z)\sigma^3(Z)}{(a^2\sigma^2(X)+b^2\sigma^2(Y)+c^2\sigma^2(Z))^{3/2}}$$

and similarly the kurtosis of $M$ is the fourth moment about the mean standardised (let's call it $\hat\mu_4(M)$) $$\hat \mu_4(M) = \frac{\mu_4(M)}{\sigma^4(M)} = \frac{a^4\mu_4(X)+b^4\mu_4(Y)+c^4\mu_4(Z)}{(a^2\mu_2(X)+b^2\mu_2(Y)+c^2\mu_2(Z))^{4/2}} \\ = \frac{a^4\hat\mu_4(X)\sigma^4(X)+b^4\hat\mu_4(Y)\sigma^4(Y)+c^4\hat\mu_4(Z)\sigma^4(Z)}{(a^2\sigma^2(X)+b^2\sigma^2(Y)+c^2\sigma^2(Z))^2}$$